# Manage Profile page: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I am using .Net Core 3 with default manage templates. However I added user fields UserFirstName and UserLastName. I updated code to correctly save this info when registering. However I have trouble with the "Manage Profile" page where I need to load and save UserFirstName and UserLastName.
I created a class UserBO in order to read and save this info and updated Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\index.cshtml.cs like this:

```
namespace InvoiceJobManager.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
    public partial class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserBO _userBO;

        public IndexModel(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            UserBO userBO
            )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userBO = userBO;
        }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Phone]
            [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "First Name")]
            public string UserFirstName { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
            public string UserLastName { get; set; }
        }

        private async Task LoadAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
            var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
            var fn = await _userBO.GetFirstName(new Guid(user.Id));

            Username = userName;

            Input = new InputModel
            {
                PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
                UserFirstName = fn
            };
        }
...
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
...
        }

    }
}
```

My ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
}
```

I updated ConfigureServices with the following:

```
services
    .AddSingleton(_ => Configuration)
    .AddScoped<IUserBO, UserBO>()
    .AddMvc()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

However I get the following runtime error when accessing the "Manage Profile" page:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'InvoiceJobManager.BusinessObjects.UserBO' while attempting to
>   activate
>   'InvoiceJobManager.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage.IndexModel'.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
>
> InvalidOperationException: Unable
>   to resolve service for type 'InvoiceJobManager.BusinessObjects.UserBO'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'InvoiceJobManager.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage.IndexModel'.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
>   lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(PageContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(PageContext
>   pageContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref
>   State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
>   isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
>   next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
>   endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Of course I could bypass all dependency injection and make a direct call to the database but that would not be very clean. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What a brain fart!!!

At first I checked for `user.UserFirstName` and `user.UserLastName` in `LoadAsync` and I am sure it was null.
I rechecked today and found out it's not and has correct values.
So the implementation is very easy actually:

```
private async Task LoadAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

    Username = userName;

    Input = new InputModel
    {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
        UserFirstName = user.UserFirstName,  // Added this line
        UserLastName = user.UserLastName     // Added this line
    };
}


public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await LoadAsync(user);
        return Page();
    }

    user.UserFirstName = Input.UserFirstName;   // Added this line
    user.UserLastName = Input.UserLastName;     // Added this line

    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

    if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
    {
        var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);

        if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting phone number for user with ID '{userId}'.");
        }
    }

    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);   // Added this line

    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
    StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
    return RedirectToPage();
}
```